# What happenes behind the scenes when debugging in VC ++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

Well i am using VC++ for quite a while now, but i want to go in more deep that when we compile and debug a code what happens behind the scenes as how the debugger does the debugging.??

Comment: Write your own, it is pretty easy on Windows.  You'll get to understand how debuggers work in the process.  Google "write a windows debugger", first hit looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the very good [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735615365) of Jeff Robbins.

Comment: And this (previous) one (http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/4023.aspx) is also very helpfull.

Comment: can u suggest a basic idea like what a debugger do when it starts?

Comment: Learning by doing...This (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43682/Writing-a-basic-Windows-debugger) article suggests the basic ideas and more!